# Erro groupby by timedate

Tags: python-3.x, mean, pandas-groupby

I have a sample dataset with 2 columns: Dates and eVal like this:

```
             eVal      Dates
0        3.622833 2015-01-01
1        3.501333 2015-01-01
2        3.469167 2015-01-01
3        3.436333 2015-01-01
4        3.428000 2015-01-01
5        3.400667 2015-01-01
6        3.405667 2015-01-01
7        3.401500 2015-01-01
8        3.404333 2015-01-01
9        3.424833 2015-01-01
10       3.489500 2015-01-01
11       3.521000 2015-01-01
12       3.527833 2015-01-01
13       3.523500 2015-01-01
14       3.511667 2015-01-01
15       3.602500 2015-01-01
16       3.657667 2015-01-01
17       3.616667 2015-01-01
18       3.534500 2015-01-01
19       3.529167 2015-01-01
20       3.548167 2015-01-01
21       3.565500 2015-01-01
22       3.539833 2015-01-01
23       3.485667 2015-01-01
24       3.493167 2015-01-02
25       3.434667 2015-01-02
26       3.422500 2015-01-02
           ...        ...
3304546  3.166000 2015-01-31
3304547  3.138500 2015-01-31
3304548  3.128000 2015-01-31
3304549  3.078833 2015-01-31
3304550  3.106000 2015-01-31
3304551  3.116167 2015-01-31
3304552  3.087500 2015-01-31
3304553  3.089167 2015-01-31
3304554  3.126667 2015-01-31
3304555  3.191667 2015-01-31
3304556  3.227500 2015-01-31
3304557  3.263833 2015-01-31
3304558  3.263667 2015-01-31
3304559  3.255333 2015-01-31
3304560  3.265500 2015-01-31
3304561  3.234167 2015-01-31
3304562  3.231167 2015-01-31
3304563  3.236333 2015-01-31
3304564  3.274667 2015-01-31
3304565  3.223167 2015-01-31
3304566  3.238333 2015-01-31
3304567  3.235000 2015-01-31
3304568  3.227333 2015-01-31
3304569  3.185333 2015-01-31
```

I want to aggregate by day and do a mean (of column eVal) for each day. I tryed to use:

```
me = time['eVal'].groupby(time['Dates']).mean()
```

but it returns me wrong values ​​of mean:

```
me.head(10)
Out[149]: 
Dates
2015-01-01    4.014973  
2015-01-02    4.006548
2015-01-03    4.010406
2015-01-04    4.034531
2015-01-05    3.988262
2015-01-06    3.972111
2015-01-07    3.989347
2015-01-08    3.959556
2015-01-09    3.995394
2015-01-10    4.048786
Name: eVal, dtype: float64
```

If I applyed an describe on groupby, groupby group incorrectly. The values ​​of the maximum and minimum, of the average, for the individual days, are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you can use below code line.

> time.groupby('Dates').mean()

I have tried this on your sample and below are sample output.

```
eVal    Dates

2015-01-01    3.506160
2015-01-02    3.450111
```

Comment: I'm sorry but in my situation the function didn't function. My df have length `len(time)
Out[7]: 3304570` . 
it seems that I calculate the descriptive statistics (min, max and average) on the total of the df and not per day

Comment: If I put the only first 24 (first day) rows in another df, the function work properly

Comment: can you check if your data frame is having only 24 records for "2015-01-01"?